# Lumen : 1s, Laravel : 5s for a simple api call?

Tags: laravel, performance, api, lumen

So I started a project not long ago for an API on Laravel, and I thought why not give Lumen a shot. But in the end, I want to use Sanctum, Socialite, etc... And I read pretty much everywhere that the performance difference is not that big nowadays anyway.

So I migrated my code from Lumen to Laravel, and after a few tweaks, everything works as before... Except that now a very simple API call takes 5s. Granted, it might be my setup - wsl2 isn't particularly fast. But still, the same call in Lumen was taking ~1000ms.

```
Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
```

**Controller:**

```
    public function register(Request $request): JsonResponse {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'phone' => 'required|string|phone',
            'phone_country' => 'required_with:phone',
        ]);

        $phone = phone($request->get('phone'), [$request->get('phone_country')]);

        try {
            $user = User::createByPhone($phone);

            return response()->json(['user' => $user->id, 'message' => 'SMS_SENT'], 201);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'User Registration Failed - ', 'error' => $e], 409);
        }
    }
```

**Function in model:**

```
    public static function createByPhone($phone) {
        return DB::transaction(function () use ($phone) {
            $user = User::create();
            $user->phoneNumbers()->create([
                'did' => $phone
            ]);

            return $user;
        });
    }
```

So, pretty simple stuff. Now, why is that taking so long? ~6000ms. Am I missing something?

(On a more general note, is there a way to cut from Laravel things that aren't needed for an API only?)

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything really wrong with your code. I guess this has something to do with the speed wsl2 can read files. We had issues with windows machines and Laravel in Docker. We added Swoole to our project and this helped alot on WSL2.

Laravel now has a first party package called [Octane](https://github.com/laravel/octane) to add Swoole to your project. You can try and install that to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it - although I still wonder why would there be such a big difference with Lumen then